# Pure CSS: hide gif as preloading animation

Tags: css

I'm working on a side project, and there is a preloading animation I need to add for the website, and it should be working when the Javascript is disabled.

Right now I have an html div and img link to a gif, like this:

```
<div class="loading">
   <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/jFIgJGFHHFxde/giphy.gif">
</div>
```

How can I use css to make this gif disappear and then show the content for the rest of the website after several seconds?

Comment: You can use keyframe animation.

Answer (score 1):

```css
@keyframes anime{
  0%{
    opacity:1;
  }
  100%{
    opacity:0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes anime{
  0%{
    opacity:1;
  }
  100%{
    opacity:0;
  }
}
@keyframes anime2{
  0%{
    opacity:0;
  }
  100%{
    opacity:1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes anime2{
  0%{
    opacity:0;
  }
  100%{
    opacity:1;
  }
}
.loading{
  animation-name:anime;
  animation-duration:1s;
  animation-delay:1s;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
#info{
  opacity:0;
  animation-name:anime2;
  animation-duration:1s;
  animation-delay:5s;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="loading">
   <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/jFIgJGFHHFxde/giphy.gif">
</div>
<div id="info">
The Quick Fox ate all of the fish
</div>
```

Comment: ensure you put keyframes with other browser prefixes